# Can I use Maven only to increment the version number of package?

Tags: maven, jenkins, asp-classic

I know it is a rather stupid question, but please bear with me.
I have to integrate Maven with a classic ASP application. 
Right now I am making an automated deployment routine with Octopus and Jenkins and I am creating zip files with the entire application that I later deploy them on different environments. I increment the version number of the zip files manually. 
The task that I have is that I must auto-increment the version number with maven. I do not want to try and build the application, but I just want to increment that number with Maven.

Is there any way that I could do this ?

Thank you

(Just to avoid any misunderstandings, it is not my idea but it is mandatory to use Maven for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the versions plugin from maven : 
http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html

With a command such as `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1`, you can basically increment the version of your maven project (include modules if any).

Depending on the tool/plugin you use for building the zip file (Apache Maven Assembly Plugin?) , you can customize it to include the version number in the zip filename

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm !!